# How to shrink a notification in notification bar in Android Lollipop?

Tags: notifications, 5.0-lollipop

I was used to shrinking and enlarging notifications for more buttons in former android version - Kitkat. Now with Lollipop I am unsure how to execute this. I want to shrink notificaitons with buttons if I do not want to use them (i used to be able to do it).

Formerly I did it by holding notification for a sec and then pulling it down to enlarge or up to shrink. It seems like it works down to enlarge but I cannot shrink. Is there a different way to do it? Or does Android decide when to make it large or small (if yes that is a sad thing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can shrink a notification by pinching in horizontally on the notification. Likewise, you can expand one by pinching out horizontally. You can see this in my beautifully-drawn diagram:

[image: Expand/Shrink]

EDIT: You can also swipe up/down using two fingers instead of one. Thanks to [eldarerathis](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/981/eldarerathis) for this addition.

Comment: Wow this actually works, thanks! And wow that it just the most stupid non intuitive way to do it. What a bad design decision. Thanks again though

Comment: It is definitely not the smartest way to design it, especially since the old gesture was *so much more convenient*.

Comment: Or swipe up/down using two fingers instead of one.

Comment: I can swipe up and down with one finger, and 2 always worked on KK and works for me on Lollipop now too!